# how to reconnect to rbd after unexpected reboot?

Tags: ceph

Ceph client mounts a rados block device (rbd). When it reboots, the rbd partion is not mounted. Restarting `rbdmap` service doesn't help. How do I connect to the rbd partition without going into the deployment server?

Answer (score 0):

In directory `/etc/ceph` you should have a file called `rbdmap`. This is read on startup and holds all information about rbd images to be mapped.

Suppose you have a pool `rbd` that contains `testimage`

```
# RbdDevice     Parameters
#poolname/imagename id=client,keyring=/etc/ceph/ceph.client.keyring
rbd/testimage       id=admin,keyring=/etc/ceph/ceph.client.admin.keyring
```

Additionally you need `ceph.conf` in `/etc/ceph` as well. This file contains the information about the monitors to connect to.

To automatically mount the images you need an entry in `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/rbd/rbd/testimage  /cephdrive  xfs defaults,noatime,_netdev    0   0
```

This has been tested with Debian stretch and stretch-backports enabled.
Should work on Debian 10, Ubuntu  and CentOS as well.